# Is it possible to create sub-sections within your field sections?

Tags: templates

Is there a way to create sections within your field sections?

```
- Field Section
    - Field
```

For example I would like the following template setup to be like this:

```
- Header
    - Header Title
    - Header Body
    - Header Image
- Introduction
    - Introduction Title
    - Introduction Body
    - Introduction Image
- Image gallery
    - Image 1
        - Image
        - Caption
        - Author
    - Image 2
        - Image
        - Caption
        - Author
    - Image 3
        - Image
        - Caption
        - Author
    - Image 4
        - Image
        - Caption
        - Author
```

But instead the implementation looks like the following

```
- Header
    - Header Title
    - Header Body
    - Header Image
- Introduction
    - Introduction Title
    - Introduction Body
    - Introduction Image
- Image gallery
    - Image 1 Image
    - Image 1 Caption
    - Image 1 Author
    - Image 2 Image
    - Image 2 Caption
    - Image 2 Author
    - Image 3 Image
    - Image 3 Caption
    - Image 3 Author
    - Image 4 Image
    - Image 4 Caption
    - Image 4 Author
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.

You should think about having separate template for `Image Gallery Item` with `Image`, `Caption` and `Author` fields

And then some multilist field maybe for selecting which images should be displayed in the gallery.

Or you may want to create your `Image Gallery Item` items as child items of the datasource of your component.

Comment: It's not possible, you have to refactor your template into other levels like Main Template which will have Header title, body. And create image item as different template and user can create image items as a child of Main Template. Like Main Item which can contains many Image items, similar to Carousel item which can have multiple slides.